# Calculating time when both apartments unoccupied - mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables to report on occupancy for 2 holiday aparments.

Columns are
id, arrivalweek, departureweek. Simple SMALLINTs

I already have a system where I can specify a period in the year by start week and an end week, and see how many weeks an individual apartment is occupied within that period. This works fine and is shown below, for example to see how many weeks apartment 1 was occupied between weeks 5 and 22 ...

```
$begin=5; // start of analysis period
$end=22;  // end of analysis period

 // ###############################################################################
// Apartment 1
// ##################################################################################
$totalperiod=0;$arrivalweek=0;$departureweek=0;$period=0;
foreach($db->query('SELECT   id, arrivalweek, departureweek FROM apartment1  WHERE departureweek > '.$begin.' AND arrivalweek < '.$end.'  ORDER BY id ASC') as $record)
{
$arrivalweek=$record['arrivalweek'];  
$departureweek=$record['departureweek']; 
if ($arrivalweek<$begin) {$arrivalweek=$begin;} // we might already be in occupancy.
if($departureweek>$end){$departureweek=$end;}   // we might not have vacated yet.
$period=$departureweek-$arrivalweek; // period for this sector
$totalperiod=$totalperiod+$period;  // add all sectors to get total period
}
echo "Time range from ".$begin." to ".$end.", for apartment 1<br>";
echo $totalperiod." = total weeks occupied for apartment 1 in that period<br>";
// ##################################################################################
// End of individual apartment occupancy code
// ##################################################################################
```

Now, I would like to be able to know how many weeks in that period BOTH apartments are unoccupied, and have struggled to find a solution. Total number of weeks when apartment 1 NOT occupied AND apartment 2 NOT occupied, over the specified time period.

Any clues much welcomed!

Thanks

G

Comment: Toward the end of determining when both are unoccupied, what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to derive a NOR function based on the date ranges for each apartment. I did this with a combo of mysql (unions and joins tried) and php but failed miserably - my experience of mysql is quite limited and I have become 'blind' to a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Not tested (no test data) but possibly something like this:-

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT Tens.a * 10 + Units.a AS weekNumber
    FROM
    (SELECT 0 AS a UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Tens,
    (SELECT 0 AS a UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Units
    HAVING weekNumber BETWEEN $begin AND $end
) allWeeks
LEFT OUTER JOIN apartment1 ON allWeeks.weekNumber BETWEEN apartment1.arrivalweek AND  apartment1.departureweek
LEFT OUTER JOIN apartment2 ON allWeeks.weekNumber BETWEEN apartment2.arrivalweek AND  apartment2.departureweek
WHERE apartment1.id IS NULL
AND apartment2.id IS NULL
```

First sub query gets a list of the weeks between $begin and $end.

This is left joined against the bookings table for each apartment (note, you probably should have a single table for both apartments, with a column defining which apartment a row relates to). The WHERE clause then ignores any rows where a match was found on the join.

Comment: Many thanks Kickstart! 

I've tried a few combos, but not succeeding so far. I made the following simple test tables... 
'
INSERT INTO `apartment1` (`id`, `arrivalweek`, `departureweek`) VALUES
(1, 3, 9),
(2, 19, 26),
(3, 35, 46);



INSERT INTO `apartment2` (`id`, `arrivalweek`, `departureweek`) VALUES
(1, 5, 10),
(2, 17, 22),
(3, 33, 47),
(4, 49, 50);'

So if we choose the range of weeks 15 to 24, I should get the answer 2 weeks, where no occupancy exists.

Or 8 to 38 should give 14 weeks total, where neither apartment were occupied.

Comment: About your suggestion of 1 table instead of 2, I was trying to get my normalisation  as atomic as possible, is it best not to take it that far?

Comment: Quite the opposite. You shouldn't be duplicating data, nor stores of data. Further if you have (say) 1000 apartments you would need 1000 tables which would be pretty much impossible to join, whereas sharing a table means no need to join. (and don't get me started on using a whole new database per customer.....;-) )